# Ubuntu Software Center > Ryzom

Tags: software-center

Many games and apps like Ryzom are not shown in my Ubuntu Software center . I tried to add other software sources but to no avail .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ryzom-isv/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ryzom
```

<sub>[Source](https://ryzomcore.atlassian.net/wiki/display/RC/Official+Ryzom+client+for+Ubuntu+and+Debian) and more possibilities.</sub>

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A simple installation method, to install manually, download it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ryzom/files/ryzom_client.7z/download), then easily just unpack the compressed downloaded file and run the script `create_menu_icon.sh`. It will install itself.